How to extract the per sample losses during the training process?
I am finetuning different models on variety of NLP tasks including abstarctive summarization, question-asnwering and classification. I am using mainly the transformers library by huggingface. I am finding it difficult to extract the sample losses in an adequate way.
Link to the summarization notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1aVWD-_iVZcMJ3Krt_nJQbrtFRtLAyPZU?usp=sharing
Link to the classification notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KicqvWNn1FnHR_dPMqnIwxtUF4OXSVo-?usp=sharing
Is there a more straightforward way to do this than what I am doing currently:
I am referring to an example on huggingface, but there they are using accelerate during the training procedure and I couldn't extract the per sample losses that way. Therefore, I am stuck with this approach of computing the loss manualy:
logits = outputs.logits.detach().cpu()
labels = batch["labels"].detach().cpu()
loss_per_sample = F.cross_entropy(logits.view(-1, logits.size(-1)), labels.view(-1), reduction='none')
loss_per_sample = loss_per_sample.view(logits.size(0), -1).mean(dim=1)

for i, id in enumerate(dataset["train"]["id"][step * train_dataloader.batch_size: (step + 1) *  train_dataloader.batch_size]):
    sample_losses[id]["loss"].append(loss_per_sample[i].item())
    predicted_summary_ids = logits[i].argmax(dim=-1)
    sample_losses[id]["predicted_summaries"].append(tokenizer.decode(predicted_summary_ids, skip_special_tokens=True))

Worth mentioning is I am using a dictionary to store the sample id alongside with the dialogue, the target summary, the epoch losses and the corresponding predicted summaries:
sample_losses = {
    id: {"text": dialogue, "target_summary": target_summary, "loss": [], "predicted_summaries": []}
    for id, dialogue, target_summary in zip(dataset["train"]["id"], dataset["train"]["text"],  dataset["train"]["summary"])
}

